# How to JOIN on the closest record that is less than a value in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

In this example, I have a table `table` with `1,3,4,8` in its `value` column, and a table `lookup` with the even numbers in its `starting` column.

I want to run a query that looks something like this

```
SELECT 
    value, starting
FROM
    table
LEFT JOIN 
    lookup ON lookup.starting < value
```

but only joins the row with the highest `starting` less than `value`.

The expected output looks like this

```
value | starting
------+-------
 1    |  null
 3    |  2
 4    |  2
 8    |  6
```

Comment: What result is your current query giving? I assume you are getting two additional rows to your desired output : (8,4) & (8,6)?

Comment: Oops and (8,2) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this:

```
SELECT value, starting
FROM table
CROSS APPLY (select top 1 starting from lookup where lookup.starting < value order by value desc) as subquery(starting)
```

The top and order parts will work together to make sure you get only one, the suitable, result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  value,
        starting
FROM    (
            SELECT  value,
                    starting,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY starting DESC) as cnt
            FROM    #Table t
                    LEFT JOIN #Lookup l
                        ON l.starting < t.value
        ) a
WHERE   cnt = 1
```